How to install discord ffmpeg to aws ec2 instance (running Windows)
I have ffmpeg installed locally onto my computer, on my computer it is configured correctly, ffmpeg is installed into the path. But I wish to install ffmpeg onto aws ec2 instance. I have WinSCP connected to my instance and directories in the instance look like this:
https://gyazo.com/737954fa634c8c62137716c6c915a095
files is where my botfiles are but which folder do I install ffmpeg to?
This is what I have been trying to do: (aws ec2 instance is connected to powershell on my computer)
Error: Unable to find a match: ffmpeg
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-44-60 ~]$ pip install ffmpeg-python
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: ffmpeg-python in /usr/bin (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/bin (from ffmpeg-python) (1.0.0)
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-44-60 ~]$ ffmpeg
-bash: ffmpeg: command not found
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-44-60 ~]$

Summary: how to install ffmpeg for discord.py onto AWS EC2, when I try and run my bot from AWS and I attempt to use my music commands (play command) I get an error saying ffmpeg is not installed (onto AWS EC2 instance) How do I install it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I clarified, check the edit

Why did you post the same question again? Please read the Help section to better understand how this site works. Do not post the same question twice.
